# Head replacement

Tags: replacement, head

Input Code

```
a[1]=UnitVector[4,1]
b[1]=1
```

Now I want replace the head of `b[1]` by `a`, something similar to

```
a@@b[1]
```

The result above is `1`, however, I want to get the result `{1,0,0,0}`

How can I do that?

Comment: `f @@@ Hold[g[1]] // ReleaseHold` do some reading on [evaluation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EvaluationOfExpressionsOverview.html) (specifically [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NonStandardEvaluation.html)). It'll help a lot.

Answer (score 4):

What's happening is that `a@@b[1]` evaluates to `Apply[a, b[1]]`, which to evaluates to `Apply[a, 1]`. This is standard evaluation; there is nothing that prevents `b[1]` from evaluating inside `Apply[a, b[1]]`. `Hold[b[1]]` prevents `b[1]` from evaluating, i.e.

```
Apply[a, Hold[b[1]], {1}]
```

> `Hold[a[1]]`

You can then apply `ReleaseHold` to remove `Hold` and evaluate `a[1]`. We can also create a function which has the `HoldAll` attribute, meaning that it won't evaluate its arguments like `Apply` does.

```
SetAttributes[replaceHead, HoldAll]
replaceHead[_[args___], h_] := h[args]
replaceHead[b[1], a]
```

> `{1, 0, 0, 0}`

The `HoldAll` attribute means that `replaceHead[b[1], a]` is not replaced by `replaceHead[1, a]` as it would normally be.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Unevaluated` to apply the head to the input expression:

```
In[139]:= Apply[a, Unevaluated[b[1]]]
Out[139]= {1, 0, 0, 0}
```